# Using a regression model to predict values

Tags: r, csv, regression, non-linear-regression

I am currently working with 2 separate CSV datasets. I have already used the first data set named PRICEtable4.1 to visualize a relationship between the x values (GBA) and the y values (PRICE). I have attached a picture of the graph right below. 
[image: Regression model]

What I need to do now is use that cubic regression model from the first CSV dataset to predict the y values (PREDICTED_PRICE) in the second CSV dataset based on the x values (GBA) given. Is there a function that lets me make that connection? The code I used to create the regression model is below

```
train_X <-  PRICEtable4.1$GBA
train_y <- PRICEtable4.1$PRICE
test_X <- PRICEtable4.1$GBA
test_y <- PRICEtable4.1$PRICE

X <- train_X
view(X)
y <- train_y
View(y)

poly_order <- 3
model <- lm (y~poly(X, poly_order))
print(model)

#MSE
test_yhat <- predict(model, data.frame (X = test_X))
MSE <- mean((test_y-test_yhat )^2)
print(MSE)

#R squared
test_ymean <- mean(test_y)
test_yhatmean <- mean( test_yhat)
R_squared <- (sum((test_yhat-test_yhatmean)*(test_y-test_ymean)))^2/(sum((test_yhat-test_yhatmean)^2)*sum((test_y-test_ymean)^2))
print(R_squared)

error2 <- data.frame(MSE=c(MSE),R_squared=c(R_squared))
View(error2)

#Visualization of the model

X_new = X
View(X_new)
y_new <- predict(model, data.frame (X = X_new))
View(y_new)
PRICEmodel <- ggplot(PRICEtable4.1,aes(x=GBA,y=PRICE))+geom_point(size=2)
PRICEmodel+geom_line(aes(x=X_new,y=y_new),color="Red") + labs(x="Gross building area (ft^2)", y="Price", title="Price Regression Model")
```

Here's a dput of the first dataset named PRICEtable4.1 (first 20 rows)

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), GBA = c(1324L, 
2120L, 1216L, 1804L, 1836L, 1228L, 1312L, 1262L, 1461L, 1120L, 
1037L, 832L, 1500L, 920L, 1565L, 1134L, 1184L, 1420L, 2082L, 
1422L), PRICE = c(1375000L, 1467000L, 549410L, 1180000L, 828000L, 
742000L, 829000L, 710000L, 775000L, 380000L, 600000L, 189000L, 
200000L, 265000L, 560000L, 300000L, 200000L, 940000L, 1050000L, 
979000L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's the dput of the second CSV dataset named Test (first 20 rows)

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), GBA = c(1324L, 
2120L, 1216L, 1804L, 1836L, 1228L, 1312L, 1262L, 1461L, 1120L, 
1037L, 832L, 1500L, 920L, 1565L, 1134L, 1184L, 1420L, 2082L, 
1422L), PRICE = c(1375000L, 1467000L, 549410L, 1180000L, 828000L, 
742000L, 829000L, 710000L, 775000L, 380000L, 600000L, 189000L, 
200000L, 265000L, 560000L, 300000L, 200000L, 940000L, 1050000L, 
979000L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(Test[1:20, ])
structure(list(ID = 1:20, BATHRM = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L), HF_BATHRM = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), HEAT = c("Forced Air", "Forced Air", "Warm Cool", 
"Forced Air", "Forced Air", "Warm Cool", "Hot Water Rad", "Forced Air", 
"Warm Cool", "Forced Air", "Forced Air", "Hot Water Rad", "Forced Air", 
"Forced Air", "Warm Cool", "Forced Air", "Forced Air", "Warm Cool", 
"Ht Pump", "Forced Air"), AC = c("Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y"), NUM_UNITS = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), ROOMS = c(9L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 
13L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 
7L), BEDRM = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), AYB = c(1870L, 1890L, 1911L, 
1920L, 1993L, 1947L, 1895L, 1910L, 1910L, 1950L, 1951L, 1928L, 
1941L, 2018L, 1939L, 2018L, 1980L, 1951L, 1910L, 1908L), YR_RMDL = c(1980L, 
1963L, NA, 2001L, 2018L, NA, 1987L, 2017L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1992L, NA, 2013L, 2005L, 2004L, 1984L), EYB = c(1967L, 1982L, 
1957L, 1972L, 2003L, 1958L, 1957L, 1964L, 1954L, 1960L, 1951L, 
1954L, 1961L, 2018L, 1957L, 2018L, 1991L, 1961L, 1975L, 1960L
), STORIES = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.75, 2, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), GBA = c(1324L, 2120L, 1216L, 1804L, 5036L, 1836L, 
1228L, 1312L, 1262L, 1461L, 1120L, 1037L, 832L, 1500L, 920L, 
1565L, 1134L, 1184L, 1420L, 2082L), BLDG_NUM = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), STYLE = c("2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", 
"2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", 
"2 Story", "2 Story", "1 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story", 
"2 Story", "2 Story", "2 Story"), STRUCT = c("Row Inside", "Row Inside", 
"Row Inside", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Row Inside", "Row Inside", 
"Row Inside", "Single", "Semi-Detached", "Single", "Row Inside", 
"Semi-Detached", "Semi-Detached", "Single", "Row Inside", "Multi", 
"Row Inside", "Row Inside"), LANDAREA = c(1575L, 1800L, 1280L, 
5000L, 10252L, 3000L, 1500L, 1641L, 1358L, 6300L, 1818L, 3500L, 
1280L, 5098L, 1899L, 5009L, 1152L, 2910L, 1762L, 1400L), ASSESSMENT_NBHD = c("Old City 2", 
"Capitol Hill", "Old City 1", "Palisades", "Chevy Chase", "Chevy Chase", 
"Eckington", "Ledroit Park", "Eckington", "Riggs Park", "Riggs Park", 
"Woodridge", "Lily Ponds", "Fort Dupont Park", "Hillcrest", "Hillcrest", 
"Congress Heights", "Congress Heights", "Old City 1", "Capitol Hill"
), PREDICTED_PRICE = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

So I need to predict and fill out the values in the "PREDICTED_PRICE" column in the second CSV dataset using the regression model I created from the first dataset

Comment: You should be able to do it using the predict function the same way as above.
`Test$PREDICTED_PRICE <- predict(model, Test)`

Comment: May want to log transform both x and y here

Comment: Echoing the advice from Alistair. This data has some very heavy tails on both axes, as a result you may want to consider a transformation of your data before regression analysis.